# How bad is it to update a UniformBuffer during its use?

Tags: vulkan

I need to update a UniformBuffer (device local, readonly in shaders) every frame or so. I'm not an expert but my understanding is that I need either to:

- Synchronize (Fence...), to be sure to not write in the buffer while it's used.
- Write in a different buffer/offset, update the DescriptorSet, and re-record the CommandBuffer.

But, let's say I don't synchronize, and simply push some fresh data in the same buffer, at the same location (offset):

#### **How bad would it be?**

Note: This question is only intended to get a better understanding of Vulkan, but definitely not to propagate bad practices.

Comment: I'm not sure how this improves one's understanding of Vulkan. The specification tells you not to do it. You know not to do it. So... whatever you would learn from this could never be something you could *use* if you intend to use Vulkan correctly.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe all of that is obvious for you, but not for me.

I knew it was a bad practice, but I didn't knew **why**. I'm not an expert in rendering, and it's long to acquire such knowledge. I tried to search in the spec but didn't found it. So I though asking to people who actually know (here, in stack overflow) could be a good idea, to understand better (_maybe_) how memory works.

And more, I thought this question could be shared by some other newbies in rendering.
But since I loose reputation (and the right to comment everywhere btw), I'm considering removing this question.

Comment: "*I knew it was a bad practice, I didn't knew why.*" But you *do* know why it is bad practice. The standard says so. That's all the "why" you need. It's not about being obvious or not obvious; if a thing says "don't do X", you don't really need to investigate deeper. And if you want to know more about what's going on behind the scenes, you're asking the wrong question. You asked about what happens if you do it; that tells you nothing about *why* that happens, which is what you really want to know.

Comment: No, I didn't knew why. I just saw some random tutorials saying "do like that", but I didn't found the reference in the standard. And when I try in my application, it's just working fine. I understand that for you it's a dumb question, poorly asked probably, but I have the right to be curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour:

> Execution and memory dependencies are used to solve data hazards, i.e. to ensure that read and write operations occur in a well-defined order. Write-after-read hazards can be solved with just an execution dependency, but read-after-write and write-after-write hazards need appropriate memory dependencies to be included between them. If an application does not include dependencies to solve these hazards, the results and execution orders of memory accesses are undefined.

Putting aside any 'Nasal Demons' intepretation of undefined behaviour, in practice I think there's a good chance that there will be rare glitches in your rendering when you're unlucky enough that the write and the read clash. It seems unlikely to me that you could cause a crash, but you could never be 100% confident of that.

Comment: Careful; "undefined results" is not the same as "undefined behavior". My interpretation of the above quote is: you don't know what value will be written, and what value will be read (if anything also accesses the same asynchronously). But it should be recoverable error (assuming no bugs in driver).